Is there an "obvious" reason for why the second derivative of an antisymmetric tensor with respect to coordinates over both of its indices equal to 0?
It was kind of difficult to word the title so I'll restate the question here. My professor took it almost as a given that
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^{\mu}\partial X^\nu} =  0$$
If $T^{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric. I for one, didn't find this immediately obvious, and I've been trying to prove it for a little while now. The context was the electromagnetic field tensor if it matters at all.
This is my attempt at proving it thus far:
Straight from the definition of an antisymmetric tensor, we have that
$$T^{\mu\nu} = -T^{\nu\mu}$$
and, taking the derivatives produces a similar identity
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\mu} = -\frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial X^\mu}$$
But, noting the antisymmetry, we can swap out the $X^\mu$ for $X^\nu$, which adds another minus sign, canceling out the one we have in the equation above
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\mu} = \frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial X^\nu}$$
Also, we can apply this in the opposite direction
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\nu} = \frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial X^\mu}$$
And finally, note that from this we also have that
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\nu} = -\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\mu}$$
Ok, now taking the derivative again with respect to the other index (in the two equations above the one directly above) yields
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\nu \partial X^\mu} = \frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial^2X^{\nu}}$$
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\mu \partial X^\nu} = \frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial^2 X^\mu}$$
But, the order in which we take derivatives does not matter
$$\frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\nu \partial X^\mu} = \frac{\partial T^{\mu\nu}}{\partial X^\mu \partial X^\nu}$$
Thus we have that
$$ \frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial^2X^{\nu}} = \frac{\partial T^{\nu\mu}}{\partial^2 X^\mu}$$
I'm pretty much stuck here, we can maybe swap the indices around a bit, but I find the notation confusing and hard to work with, so I don't feel super confident when doing so. Is there an easier way to realize this perhaps? It wasn't even something my professor said was "obvious", he just sort of assumed it implicitly.

Your thinking is correct, but way over complicated. It suffices to note that the tensor is antisymmetric, while partial derivatives are symmetric.


Your "equation" $\partial T^{\mu \nu}/\partial x^\mu= \partial T^{\nu \mu}/\partial x^\nu$ does not make sense, as the LHS has a free index $\nu$ whereas the free index on the   RHS is $\mu$. 2. As explained in the answer below, the solution to your problem simply follows from combining $T^{\mu \nu}= -T^{\nu \mu}$ and $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu=\partial_\nu \partial_\mu$. 3. Yes, it is obvious.



$\partial_\mu \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=-\partial_\mu \partial_\nu T^{\nu\mu}$ (by antisymmetry of $T$)


$\partial_\mu \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=-\partial_\nu \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ (by changing name of dummy indices on the right)

$\partial_\mu \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=-\partial_\mu \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ (by switching the commuting derivatives on the right)


